# Error when applying a function multiple times

Tags: c++

I wrote a function to find all combinations of integers between two bounds. To do this, I wrote a function with the same name that finds all combinations of integers between two bounds of a certain size.

In main, I set up a loop to call this function multiple times. When it is ran more than once with bounds that are sufficiently far apart, it causes an error, that is, the code reaches the logic error in the first function.

I do not know why multiple passes in the while-loop causes a problem because the variables should be reset each time.

```
#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>

#define VAR1 3
#define VAR2 8


bool nextCombination(std::vector<int> &combo, int numItems, \
                     int lowerBound, int upperBound) {

  if (combo.empty()) { //This is the first take.
    for (int i = 0; i < numItems; ++i) {
      combo.push_back(lowerBound + i);
    }
    return true;
  } else if (combo[0] >= upperBound - numItems) { //This cleans up.
    combo.clear();
    return false;
  } else {
    for (int i = 0; i < numItems; ++i) {
      if (i >= numItems || combo[i]+1 != combo[i+1]) {
        ++combo[i]; //This extends the front of the stack.
        return true;
      } else { //This pushes the first part of the stack back.
        combo[i] = lowerBound + i;
      }
    }
  }

  throw std::logic_error("There is an error with nextCombination.");
}


bool nextCombination(std::vector<int> &combo, int lowerBound, int upperBound) {
  int numItems = combo.size();
  if (numItems >= upperBound - lowerBound) {
    combo.clear();
    return false;
  } else if (numItems == 0) {
    combo.push_back(0);
    return true;
  } else {
    if (nextCombination(combo, numItems, lowerBound, upperBound)) {
      return true;
    } else {
      combo.clear(); //This line shouldn't be needed. 
      return (nextCombination(combo, numItems+1, lowerBound, upperBound));
    }
  }
}


int main() {
  for (int i = 0; i < VAR1; ++i) {
    std::vector<int> combo;
    while (nextCombination(combo, 0, VAR2)) ;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You'll be glad to hear you don't need anyone's help to figure this out, just a tool you already have: your debugger! This is exactly what a debugger is for. It runs your program, one line at a time, and shows you what's happening. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer, no exceptions. With your debugger's help you should be able to quickly find all problems in this and all future programs you write, without having to ask anyone for help. Have you tried using your debugger, already? If not, why not? What did your debugger show you?

Comment: [OT] ```\``` isn't required at end of line.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I having been using gdb and trying general debugging for several hours on this.

Comment: @user314 the fist step in debugging is identifying when and where your expectations (of the code path /  variable values) diverges from what you observe in the debugger. Have you managed to do that?

Comment: Your program exhibits undefined behavior by way of accessing an index out of bounds: [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/q3ejPa) (I added a bounds check before `combo` elements are accessed) . Why this undefined behavior only manifests when you run the loop more than once, I don't know, and it's not particularly interesting to find out.

Comment: So, if you've been "trying general debugging for several hours on this", then "what did your debugger show you"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand the algorithm, but the problems are clear enough.

Step one, reduce the size of the problem I chose

```
#define VAR1 1
#define VAR2 2
```

Run the code, crash in operator[] here,

```
if (i >= numItems || combo[i]+1 != combo[i+1])
```

Values of variables

```
combo = vector of size 1
numItems = 1
i = 0
```

`combo[i+1]` is a subscript out of bounds error.

It doesn't take long to step through the code to get to this point. It happens immediately on the second iteration of the inner loop in main. Since I don't understand what your code is trying to do I can't suggest a fix. But hopefully the error is clearer to you now.

Since it seems you were unaware of this subscripting issue, you should change to using `at` instead of `[]` that way you get defined behaviour even on a subscript error.

Comment: If VAR1 is 1, then the for-loop in main should never make a pass and the program shouldn't do anything. Also, when I made these changes, my code did not throw an error. I choose different values of VAR1 and VAR2 because I did not get an error when these were so small.

Comment: @user314 That's not true, as your debugger will tell you.

Comment: @user314 To clarify, second iteration of the **inner** loop in main.

Comment: @user314 See my comments about using `at` instead of `[]`. Clearly your debugger is more forgiving of subscript errors than mine.

Comment: Okay, I see what you are saying. Thank you! Just curious, which debugger do you use?

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio

Comment: @user314 Learn to know your tools. Virtually every implementation has a checked/debug mode with some sort of runtime validations. For example [here](https://godbolt.org/z/ozWW4h) is gcc with `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` reporting the (first) out-of-bounds access.